# am not getting list items individually

Tags: python, networkx

```
nodes=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
G.add_edges_from([('a','f'),('a','d'),('a','b'),('a','e'),('b','g'),('b','e'),('b','c'),('c','b'),('c','d'),('d','a'),('d','c'),('e','b'),('e','a'),('f','a'),('g','b')])
nodlen=len(nodes)
for i in range(nodlen):
    print(G.neighbors(nodes[i]))
```

I am getting the entire list (as below), but I need to access the individual elements from this list.

```
['e', 'b', 'f', 'd']
['e', 'c', 'g', 'a']
['b', 'd']
['c', 'a']
['b', 'a']
['a']
['b']
```

Comment: So why not use indexing on the return value of `G.neighbors()` then? Python tip: don't loop over `range()` when you can just loop over the list itself: `for node in nodes:`, `print('Neighbours for {}'.format(node))`, `for neighbour in G.neighbors(node):`, `print('    ', neighbour)`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Graph.neighbors()` method](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.neighbors.html) returns a bog-standard Python `list` object. Just index into it:

```
neighbors = G.neighbors(nodes[i])
print('First neighbor', neighbors[0])
```

or loop over it to get to each individual element of the list.

In Python, you usually do not generate indices to access all elements in a list, you just loop over the list itself; the `for` construct is a [Foreach loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop):

```
nodes=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
G.add_edges_from([('a','f'),('a','d'),('a','b'),('a','e'),('b','g'),('b','e'),('b','c'),('c','b'),('c','d'),('d','a'),('d','c'),('e','b'),('e','a'),('f','a'),('g','b')])

for node in nodes:
    print('Neighbors for', node)
    for neighbor in G.neighbors(node):
        print('    ', neighbor)
    print()
```

Comment: sorry martijn, i think my question was not right, actually by individual element i mean  ['e', 'b', 'f', 'd'] not e b f d....like that... hope u got it . i want to compare each of these set with the other one...ie ['e', 'b', 'f', 'd'] compare this with the remaining section ['e', 'c', 'g', 'a']
['b', 'd']
['c', 'a']
['b', 'a']
['a']
['b']

Comment: @akhilamahadevan: that sounds like you are trying to do something extremely inefficient. Why not explain (in your question) what you are trying to do? You can loop over the remaining nodes *again*, in a nested loop, and get the neighbors for each of those other nodes to compare against, but nesting loops leads to quadratic execution which means *slow*.

Answer (score 0):

```
nodes=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
G.add_edges_from([('a','f'),('a','d'),('a','b'),('a','e'),('b','g'),('b','e'),('b','c'),('c','b'),('c','d'),('d','a'),('d','c'),('e','b'),('e','a'),('f','a'),('g','b')])
nodlen=len(nodes)
for i in range(nodlen):
    all_items = G.neighbors(nodes[i])
    for one in all_items:
        print one
```